# Disable status bar on rooted device(system signed application) in device locked mode

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-source, android-statusbar

I am working on a kiosk application which would work in single app mode on device and the activity would be on top everytime. I even want the user to restrict use of notification panel when the activity is on top. For this I am using below system API  :

```
try {
            android.app.StatusBarManager service = (StatusBarManager) context.getSystemService("statusbar");
            service.disable(DISABLE_EXPAND);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStrackTrace();
        }
```

This works correctly when user try to scroll down the notification panel, but if screen lock is configured and user tries to scroll down the panel, it doesn't gets disabled and expands.

Can someone help me understand what could be the possible issue.

Comment: The main issue is they really never meant to make the status bar configurable like that, since it would be easy for an app to use it to lock a user out of his own device.  You may want to consider a custom rom for your device if you need this, with it disabled at that level.

Comment: @GabeSechan Okay, but I believe these APIs can be used by the application which are platform signed or act as system application..

Comment: It's actually kind of a hidden API.  There's no documentation of it on their website.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/StatusBarManager. is empty.  Not saying you're wrong for using it, I just wouldn't be surprised at the lack of polish in it.  Building a good kiosk mode app is easier than it used to be, but it still has a lot of things like this to deal with.